# GNU/GUIX fails to locate custom modules specified in a manifest

Tags: guix

I'm trying run `guix package` install for following manifest:

```lisp
(specifications->manifest
'("noguix-hugo" ;; A CUSTOM MODULE implemented in /module/root-1/site-lisp/nonguix-hugo.scm
  "go"))
```

The custom module in the manifest is declared as follows:

```lisp
(define-module (nonguix-hugo)
  ;; implementation detail
  ;; ....
)
```

And the installation command looks like:

```sh
guix package --load-path="/module/root1/site-lisp"   \
             --load-path="/module/root-2/site-lisp"  \
             --manifest="/path/to/manifest.scm"      \
             --profile="/path/to/profile"
```

The command fails with error message:

**guix package: error: noguix-hugo: unknown package**

However, building the `noguix-hugo` using `guix build` command works just fine

```sh
guix build   --load-path="/module/root1/site-lisp"   \
             --load-path="/module/root-2/site-lisp"  \
             nonguix-package

# The command builds and outputs the module location as expected 
# /gnu/store/7js349wb17371225njzll9gma8kmwf-nonguix-hugo-1.0
```

My **question**:

Why does Guix succeed to locate the module when building it,
but can't seem to locate it when specified in a manifest file.

I even tried adding a `(use-modules (nonguix-hugo))` to the manifest and setting `GUIX_PACKAGE_PATH` as specified in[1], yet  the install  still fails.

## References

[1] https://guix.gnu.org/manual/en/html_node/Package-Modules.html

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out this was a typo in the manifest:

```lisp
(specifications->manifest
'("noguix-hugo"
  "go"))
```

which should be corrected to:

```lisp
(specifications->manifest
  '("nonguix-hugo" ;; <= this line
    "go"))
```

Sheesh!....